# Advice on map function using setitem

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm struggling to understand a script from "the Python Book". The script removes duplicates from a list, by putting every element into a dict as a key (for example with `'none'` as value) and then returns the `dict.keys()`. The script is as follows:

```
from operator import setitem
def distinct(l):
    d = {}
    map(setitem, (d,)*len(l), l, [])
    return d.keys()
```

I have run the script, passing a list which contains duplicates to `distinct()`:

```
li = [1, 5, 6, 1, 8]
x = distinct(li)
print(x)
```

However when I run the script and print the result I just get:

```
dict_keys([])
```

Can somebody give me an example of how I can run the `distinct()` function so I can get some meaningful output? Also please can someone explain how the map function works with the inner `setitem` function. I have read about `setitem`, but I'm  not sure how it is working here. I'm confused by the first the argument to `setitem`:

```
(d,)*len(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, `distinct` cannot work in Python 3, as `map` is a *class* that, in this case, returns an iterable that will call `setitem` on demand as you iterate over it. As the return value is ignored, `setitem` will never be called.

In Python 2, `map` was a function that acted much like a list comprehension: it returned a list of the return values from calling `setitem` on the elements of the given iterables. But it has never been considered good practice to use `map` (or a list comprehension) simply for the side effect of the function.

If you don't care about the resulting sequence or list, use a proper `for` loop, instead of creating a `map` instance that is never iterated over.

```
def distinct(l):
    d = {}
    for k in l:
        d[k] = None
    return list(d)
```

Or use a dict comprehension:

```
def distinct(l):
    return list({k: None for k in l})
```

---

The purpose of `(d,)*len(l)` was to create sequence of references to `d`, so that every call to `setitem` modified the same `dict`.

Adapting my first example to use `setitem` would look like

```
def distinct(l):
    d = {}
    for k in l:
        setitem(d, k, None)
    return list(d)
```

Note that `list(map(setitem, (d,)*len(l), l, []))` would never have done anything. `[]` was a third iterable to whose *contents*, not the list itself, would be used as the third argument to `setitem`. `map` only iterates until the shortest of the iterables is exhausted, and the empty list would be exhausted immediately.